# @clerk/clerk-react: Missing publishableKey

Tags: reactjs, next.js, clerk

> Error: @clerk/clerk-react: Missing publishableKey. You can get your
> key at https://dashboard.clerk.com/last-active?path=api-keys.

I got this error message when running my project with `npm run dev`

But I got those keys in my .env.local file, is there something I missed? Do I need to install some dependencies or something?

Answer (score 0):

On the root of your application, where you have the ClerkProvider, you need to put the publishableKey. Example:

```
<ClerkProvider
   publishableKey={Constants.expoConfig.extra.clerkPublishableKey}
   tokenCache={tokenCache}
>
```